# Semantic issue: missing '[' at start of message send expression

Tags: ios, nslog, afnetworking, testflight

I get a weird semantic issue:

> missing '[' at start of message send expression

and a parse issue:

> Expected ']'

in `NSLog` line of `AFURLConnectionOperation.m`:

```
 @catch(NSException *e) { caughtException = e; }
 if(caughtException) {
   NSLog(NSLocalizedString(@"Unhandled exception on %@ networking thread: %@, userInfo: %@", nil), NSStringFromClass([self class]), caughtException, [caughtException userInfo]); 
 }
 [exceptionPool drain];
```

after I added

```
#define NSLog(__FORMAT__, ...) TFLog((@"%s [Line %d] " __FORMAT__), __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, __LINE__, ##__VA_ARGS__)
```

to my project's pre-compile file: `Proj-Prefix.pch`

How can I fix this error?
I searched but without any workaround except comment out the `NSLog` line..

Thanks in advance!

---

EDIT:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"Unhandled exception on %@ networking thread: %@, userInfo: %@", nil), NSStringFromClass([self class]), caughtException, [caughtException userInfo]]);
```

and

```
NSLog(@"Unhandled exception on %@ networking thread: %@, userInfo: %@", NSStringFromClass([self class]), caughtException, [caughtException userInfo]);
```

are okay.

**But why the original one does not?** :?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think about the macro expansion.  In your macro, you're trying to use string literal concatenation:

```
(@"%s [Line %d] " __FORMAT__)
```

But the value of the `__FORMAT__` parameter is `NSLocalizedString(@"Unhandled exception on %@ networking thread: %@, userInfo: %@", nil)`, which is *not* a string literal.  The expansion looks like this:

```
(@"%s [Line %d] " NSLocalizedString(@"Unhandled exception on %@ networking thread: %@, userInfo: %@", nil))
```

Clearly that's erroneous syntax.  The error is made extra-inscrutable because `NSLocalizedString` is itself a macro (defined in `NSBundle.h`), so the full expansion looks like this:

```
(@"%s [Line %d] " [[NSBundle mainBundle] localizedStringForKey:(@"Unhandled exception on %@ networking thread: %@, userInfo: %@") value:@"" table:nil])
```

By the way, you should not use `__FORMAT__` as your macro parameter name.  All identifiers that begin with two underscores are reserved.  (Also reserved are all identifiers that begin with an underscore followed by a capital letter.)